# Rails: render a form with predefined values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, templates

I would like to modify default method for rendering form (produced automatically using scaffold) so that it would fill certain field with a predefined value passed in a parameter.

I imagine the view line responsible for form rendering could look like this

```
<% render 'form' arg %>
```

Then I would like to be able to access `arg` in `_from.html.erb` so that I could insert it in one of the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% render 'form', :arg => @arg %>
```

Then within your partial you have access to the value `arg`.

Scroll down to "3.4.4 Passing Local Variables" in the [Layouts and Rendering Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).